# Rails modules and routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, routes, include

I'd like to include `TestModule` in `MyModule`:

```
# in test_module.rb
module TestModule
    SOMETHING = [1, 2, 3]
end

# in my_module.rb
module MyModule
    include TestModule

    def my_method
        "testing"
    end
end
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
Routing Error: uninitialized constant MyModule::TestModule
```

I've double-checked the rails naming convention. **Any idea why this isn't working?**

**More info**: `config.autoload_paths += ...` in `application.rb` is commented out. However other modules in `/lib` are being loaded somehow.

**More info 2**: I think rails can't see the new file `test_module.rb`. If I add a new module to an existing file containing a module then including the new module works. Is there some sort of rails clean-up or refresh process for the $LOAD_PATH or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try with this:

```
# in my_module.rb

load 'test_module.rb'

module MyModule
   include ::TestModule

   def my_method
      "testing"
   end
end
```

to refer to top-level namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a "require" to the top of the file like this:

```
# in my_module.rb
require 'test_module'
module MyModule
  include TestModule
  ...
```